# How do I exit from a try-catch block in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I want to exit from inside a `try` block:

```
function myfunc
{
   try {
      # Some things
      if(condition) { 'I want to go to the end of the function' }
      # Some other things
   }
   catch {
      'Whoop!'
   }

   # Other statements here
   return $whatever
}
```

I tested with a `break`, but this doesn't work. It breaks the upper loop if any calling code is inside a loop.

Comment: I believe only VB.net has an "exit try". Though the script block trick below is rather clever!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An extra scriptblock around `try/catch` and the `return` in it may do this:

```
function myfunc($condition)
{
    # Extra script block, use `return` to exit from it
    .{
        try {
            'some things'
            if($condition) { return }
            'some other things'
        }
        catch {
            'Whoop!'
        }
    }
    'End of try/catch'
}

# It gets 'some other things' done
myfunc

# It skips 'some other things'
myfunc $true
```

Comment: Nice trick (because yes, this is a trick). Why using a dot before the first brace ? I tested without and seems nice too.

Comment: It should not work without the dot (in this case the function creates and outputs the script block). The dot operator invokes the script in the current scope. There is also the `&`. It can be used for invocation in a new scope (for example in order to hide some inner variables from the rest of the function).

Comment: As for the *trick*... well, PowerShell itself does not provide anything for exiting `try/catch`.

Comment: What's wrong with just 'if($condition) { return }' ?, seems to work for me

Comment: @Shay Levy - This would be "return from the whole function", not "go to the end of try/catch".

Comment: @RomanKuzmin  gotcha, I thought the OP wanted to exit the function. +1

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to do what you want is to negate the condition and put the "other things" into the "then" block.

```
function myfunc {
  try {
    # some things
    if (-not condition) {
      # some other things
    }
  } catch {
    'Whoop!'
  }

  # other statements here
  return $whatever
}
```

Comment: No, because I may have several points where I want to exit the 'try' block.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question then. Besides, that can be achieved just fine by nesting additional `if`-statements. Not to mention that `try/catch` blocks aren't really something you "exit" from. Trying to do so (multiple times no less) reeks of an attempt to work around rather than fix broken program logic.

Comment: This is already perfectly mentionned in the first sentence, and in the title : "I want to exit from inside a try block". And the first answer is already (nearly) perfect.

Comment: FTR: You did *not* mention *anywhere* that you wanted to exit at more than one point, not in the first sentence, not in the headline, and not in your code sample. I offered a clean solution. You're free to ignore it.

Comment: "I want to exit from inside a try block". Why do you want to find a flaw in this ? The previous answer fullfill that. And the comments below it confirm the question was clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
function myfunc
{
   try {
      # Some things
      if(condition)
      {
          goto(catch)
      }
      # Some other things
   }
   catch {
      'Whoop!'
   }

   # Other statements here
   return $whatever
}
```

Comment: I don't think OP wanted to trigger the catch. I think they wanted to jump completely outside of the try-catch. If I recall correctly however, there's an implicit `finally {}` block that your goto might work with.

Comment: `goto(catch)`does not work for me. PowerShell version 5.1. I get an error saying `The term 'catch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.` So I used the "usual" way of getting out of the try: throw an exception - which brings me to the catch-block immediately.